# Windows Task Manager bytes received counter bugged?

Tags: windows-7, task-manager

I have noticed a suspiciously high "Bytes Received" count in Windows 7 Task Manager of 18,446,744,073,709,022,932, or roughly 18 exabytes!

[image: 18 exabytes!]

Weirdly, as I was typing this the count reset. I suspected an integer overflow, and indeed this value is approximately 2^64.

A quick Fermi analysis gives a download time, at a generous 1 Gb/s, of almost 545 years!

Now, I haven't actually reset my computer for some time, preferring to hibernate rather than restart, but the uptime is still only around 28.5 days. To clock the count would require a constant download speed of about 7.5 Tb/s.

Is the count bugged or does it measure some other internal data transfers?

Comment: Definately not actual data. More likely actual data got corrupted and system is just showing the largest value it can.

Answer (score 0):

18,446,744,073,709,022,932 bytes would be probably impossible to achieve in 28.5 days. Most likely, as Roh_mish wrote, the data was most likely false, and the counter would most likely be either reading from a different source (Very unlikely, all, if not most programs on your PC would transfer exabytes of data), or is just plain broken. The best move from now, would be to hard reset your PC to clear out the RAM and most likely eliminate the problem.

*Strangely enough, my PC says that I have recieved 0 bytes....*